# How to Update Excel sheet data using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to update excel data for that i have used following query--

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SportTech"].ConnectionString); OdbcCommand cmd; con.Open();

string query = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET POSITION=\"" + pos + "\",Time=\"" + time + "\",Point=\"" + point + "\" WHERE NAME=" + name;

cmd = new OdbcCommand(query,con);
            string x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
```

but the query is showing error----

> ERROR [42000Ձ] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE
>   statement.

So please help me